# Link to an element which is inside of a bootstrap collapse element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, collapsable

I have a link outside of a `collapse` element to an anchor inside of the collapsed content.
[See my plnkr example.](http://embed.plnkr.co/fEThkn/preview)

If I collapse the `panel`at the bottom the anchor tag is not executed anymore. What I want to implement is the following:

If I click on an anchor which is currently not visible (because it is e.g. in an collapsed area), then I want to extend the containing area and then apply the link.

Any ideas how I could accomplish this?

Thanks a lot

Comment: can you use jQuery or only pure js?

Comment: jQuery is already present, sure! I'm using Bootstrap as well!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(function(){
  $(document).on('click', 'a[href^="#"]', function(ev){
    var targetId = $(ev.target).attr('href'),
      $target = $(targetId);

      $target.parents('.collapse').addClass('in').css({height: ''});
  });
})
```

Like this? http://plnkr.co/edit/R2Fjsz9JnLkWEvFKUaAg?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

```
// open collapsed items when clicking on the corresponding link
$(document).on('click', 'a[href^="#"]', function(ev){
    var targetId = $(ev.target).attr('href'),
    $target = $(targetId);

    $target.parents('.collapse').addClass('show');
});
```

Same as accepted answer but for usage with Bootstrap Collapse elements